# How to make animation position start from last position

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, position

How to implement an animation in Unity relative to the last position. Normally when an animation is implemented in Unity each loop starts from the same position. I want to implement an animation relative to the last position of the animated object to avoid using forces or math calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I figured it out:

**Unity Animation relative to last position without looping**

This code solves the problem regarding animations based on last relative position. In this example, each time we press Fire1 a box will be animated to move from X = 0 to X = 10 Using the animation will help us to provide richer transitions and smooth movements based on curves without the problem of looping.

The idea is to have the animated object inside an empty parent so the animation of the object will be based into local position.

When the animation is finished we update the object and its parent location to match in the last position.

If you have any doubts please ask.

```
#pragma strict

/**
* Animation in Unity Relative to last position without looping
* @autor Knskank3
* http://stackoverflow.com/users/1287772/knskan3
* 04/09/2014
**/

/*
    This code solves the problem regarding animations based on last relative ImagePosition
    In this example, each time we press Fire1 a box will be animated to move from X = 0 to X = 10
    Using the animation will help us to provide richer transitions and smooth movements based on curves
    without the problem of looping
*/


// This var will determine if the animation is started
public var animation_started : boolean = false;
// This var will determine if the animation is finished
public var animation_finished : boolean = true;

function Update () {

    // if user triggers Fire1
    if( Input.GetButtonUp('Fire1')){

        // initialize the flags
        animation_started = true;
        animation_finished = false;

        // Start the animation
        // this animation moves the box from local X = 0 to X = 10 using a curve to deaccelerate
        animation.Play("boxanim");
    }

}

/* This function is trigger at the end of the animation */
public function animationFinished() : void {
    animation_finished = true;
}

/*  
    At the end of the frame if the animation is finished
    we update the position of the parent to the last position of the child
    and set the position of the child to zero inside the parent.
*/
function LateUpdate () {
    // if the animation is finished and it was started
    if(animation_finished && animation_started) {
        // set the flag
        animation_started = false;
        // update the parent position
        transform.parent.position = transform.position;
        // update the box position to zero inside the parent
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```